# $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$'s Taylor expansion about a point $a\in\mathbb{R} $, given by $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0} ^ \infty$ $a_n (x -a)^n$. Radius of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Consider its Taylor expansion about a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x)=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n.$$
What is the radius of convergence?

My try:
$\tan^{-1}(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5}..........$
Differentiating both sides I get

$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 +x^4 -.............$

How can I proceed from here?

Can anyone please help me.

Answer is $\sqrt{a^2+1}$.

Comment: Find the inverse of it.   Then see if you can come up with THAT somewhere

Comment: inverse of whom?

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2+1}$.  I don't know if that will actually help or not.

Comment: basically look for $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ as something to keep less than ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a simple proof by real analytic methods but it is elementary when you consider the complex function $\frac 1 {1+z^{2}}$. The largest disc around a on which the function is analytic has radius $(1+a^{2})^{1/2}$, the distance from a to the points $i,-i$.